# VHDL referenced context element

Tags: vhdl

I am implementing something in VHDL, and I don`t understand the errors that I get:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.primitive.all;

entity LogicF is
    port(A,B,C:in std_logic; Y:out std_logic);
end LogicF;
architecture STRUCTURAL of LogicF is
signal notA, notB, andSign:std_logic;
begin  
    inv1:inverter port map (i=>A,o=>notA);
    inv2:inverter port map (i=>B,o=>notB);
    si1:and2 port map (i1=>notA, i2=>notB, o=>andSign);
    sau1:or2 port map (i1=>andSign, i2=>C, o=>Y);
end STRUCTURAL;
```

Error: (3,10): Cannot find referenced context element.
Error: (8,1): Cannot find referenced entity declaration "LogicF"

Comment: There is a package "primitive" not shown here. You may need to post the package (not its body) in the question. Was it successfully compiled into library "Work" before compiling this? Which tool is giving the error?

Answer (score 0):

As Brian points out Line 3, Character 10 (3,10) is the first character of the word `primitive` in `use.work.primitive.all;`.  It seems the package hasn't been in the working library.

> %% ghdl -a LogicF.vhdl
>   LogicF.vhdl:3:10: primary unit "primitive" not found in library "work"
>   ghdl: compilation error
>   %%

The question about which tool comes from the second error at (8,1), the entity LogicF did not successfully analyze and wasn't placed in the working library.

IEEE Std 1076 (the LRM), **Design units and their analysis**, **Order of analysis**:

> If any error is detected while attempting to analyze a design unit,
>   then the attempted analysis is rejected and has no effect whatsoever
>   on the current working library.

The second error comes from the entity `LogicF` not being present in a referenced library.

(The LRM) same section (11.4 -1993, 13.5 -2008):

> The rules defining the order in which design units can be analyzed are
>   direct consequences of the visibility rules. In particular:
>
> ```
> a.  A primary unit whose name is referenced within a given design unit must be analyzed prior to the analysis of the given design unit.
>
> b.  A primary unit must be analyzed prior to the analysis of any corresponding secondary unit.
> ```

An entity is a primary unit (`LogicF`) an architecture (`STRUCTURAL`) is a secondary unit.

When I used ghdl to analyze your design 'file' it quit after the first error.  In this case because the second design unit was a secondary unit, the first failing was sufficient to stop analysis from succeeding.  If there were further unrelated design units their analysis could have continued should they have proven to be error free (and didn't depend on the package primitives).

What's missing from the error messages are explanations of any assumptions, which are typically found in the tool implementation's documentation.

To answer Brian's question in his comment the format of the error message is from Aldec, apparently the Aldec-HDL tool (Google *is* useful betimes).

His was a professional curiosity question, Brian is one of the ghdl developers.  There is no requirement VHDL that an error requires you to not analyze further design units found in the same design file.  It's an implementation detail, where now we know what Aldec does.

Aldec doesn't share documentation other than with customers which otherwise makes it hard to seek third party help.  You see a lot of universities publish tutorials on using Aldec tools.

I found the error message in another third party forum where the vendor was identified.